# Step using Firebase Cloud Messaging Plugin in ionic framework

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic-native

I want to get a notification for my ionic application (android & ios).I want to use Firebase Cloud Messaging. Did I need to install only Cordova-FCM-plugin or I need to install another plugin too like Cordova-firebase-plugin and PhoneGap-plugin-push. How about firebase firestore-plugin? did I need to install it too?

I already build apps and install Cordova-FCM-plugin then run the apps but can't get the firebase token. Get this error:

> Error: exec proxy not found for :: FCMPlugin :: registerNotification

Answer (score 1):

Go through this tutorial if you want to send push notifications using firebase - 
[Firebase notifications in Ionic](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic-native-with-firebase-fcm-push-notifications-ios-android/). Also, refer to the official ionic documentation for the same. [Official documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/)

Comment: yes, I already follow ionic documentation about push notification. I want to know which one better, Cordova-plugin-fcm or PhoneGap-plugin-push.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OneSignal or cordova-plugin-push,
If you decide to use cordova push plugin then follow this link https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

otherwise i would recommend you use onesignal for sending and recieveing push notifications
 https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK

Answer (score 1):

You need to change in below file :
    “AppDelegate+FCM”

Where you can find the below method:
    customDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Please replace below :

```
[FIRApp configure];

    with this

 // [START configure_firebase]
    if(![FIRApp defaultApp]){
        [FIRApp configure];
    }
```